# windows timestamp (C++)

Tags: c++, math, timestamp

I creating windows timestamp() function and I got wrong numbers checking by PHP microtime() function:

- **C++** = 1409802313
- **PHP** = 1410655505

In this fallowing C++ writed code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream> // <--- Console I/O
#include <cstdlib> // <--- Command Line
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void print(string value){cout << value;}

string parseStr(int value)
{
ostringstream stream;
stream<<value<<flush;

return stream.str();
}


// ============================================================
//                         TIMESTAMP
// ============================================================
string timestamp()
{
SYSTEMTIME system_time;
GetLocalTime(&system_time);

int year = system_time.wYear;
int month = system_time.wMonth;
int day = system_time.wDay;
int hour = system_time.wHour;
int minute = system_time.wMinute;
int second = system_time.wSecond;
int milliseconds = system_time.wMilliseconds;

int day_of_year = 0;
 if (month > 1){day_of_year += 31;} // Sausis
 if (month > 2){day_of_year += 28;} // Vasaris
 if (month > 3){day_of_year += 31;} // Kovas
 if (month > 4){day_of_year += 30;} // Balandis
 if (month > 5){day_of_year += 31;} // Geguze
 if (month > 6){day_of_year += 30;} // Birzelis
 if (month > 7){day_of_year += 31;} // Liepa
 if (month > 8){day_of_year += 31;} // Rugpjutis
 if (month > 9){day_of_year += 30;} // Rugsejis
 if (month > 10){day_of_year += 31;} // Spalis
 if (month > 11){day_of_year += 30;} // Lapkritis
 if (month > 12){day_of_year += 31;} // Gruodis
day_of_year += day;

int time = 0;
time += (year - 1970) * 31536000;
time += day_of_year * 86400;
time += hour * 3600;
time += minute * 60;
time += second;

string time_string;
time_string = parseStr(time);

return time_string;
}
// ============================================================

int main()
{
 while(true)
 {
 system("cls");

 string time = timestamp();
 print(time);

 Sleep(100);
 }

return 0;
}
```

Does i calculating something wrong or something wrong with integer types? :(

Comment: `month_of_year > 12`? When can the month be more than 12?

Comment: Instead of the screen shots, which are hard to read, could you just post the timestamps you're getting from your code and PHP?

Comment: (month_of_year > 12) is just comment to don't forget later. :)

Comment: C++ showing 1409802313 ant PHP 1410655505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
time += (year - 1970) * 31536000;
```

`31536000` is the number of seconds in 365 days. But there have been 11 leap days since 1970, those years have 366 days. You need to add `86400` for each of the leap days.

The difference between your two results is 853192. This is a little less than 10 days, so I'm not sure what happened to the 11th leap day. It's also 3 hours less than 10 days (+ 8 seconds, which I guess is the time between your two tests); that's because Unix timestamps are based on GMT, not local time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than roll your own timestamp would using this work:

```
time_t epochtime = time(NULL);
```

the variable epochtime should contain the number of seconds since the beginning of 1970.

Your code doesn't account for leap years which probably makes a difference in your computations vs PHP.